# Execute methods inside CRON JOBS

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, cron

My question is about executing a method inside a Cron Job in Spring boot. I have a class named **Task** below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task", schema = "public")
public class Task {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private Long id;

 @NotEmpty
 private String date;

 @NotEmpty
 private String startTime;

 @NotEmpty
 private String stopTime;

 @NotEmpty
 @Column(length=1000)
 private String description;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="USER_EMAIL")
 private User user;

 public Long getId() {
    return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
 }
 public String getDate() {
    return date;
 }
 public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
 }
 public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
 }
 public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
 }
 public String getStopTime() {
    return stopTime;
 }
 public void setStopTime(String stopTime) {
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
    return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
 }
 public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }
 public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
 }

 public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description, User user) {
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
    this.description = description;
    this.user = user;
 }

 public Task(String date, String startTime, String stopTime, String description) {
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.stopTime = stopTime;
    this.description = description;
 }

 public Task() {
 }
```

}

The task has a **stopTime**, and I want to delete that task when passes the deadline. The time will checked from a **Cron job** method as shown below

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    logger.info("Cron Task :: Execution Time - {}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
}
```

than in TaskRepository I have created a query to take the time of deadline of all tasks

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
@Modifying
@Query("select stopTime from Task ")
ZonedDateTime showEndTimeTasks(ZonedDateTime stopTime);
}
```

And here is the delete method

```
@GetMapping("deleteTask")
public void deleteTask(@RequestParam long id, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    taskService.deleteTask(id);
    response.sendRedirect("/profile");
}
```

With all this things how can I  delete automatically all **tasks** that have passed the deadline?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
public void scheduleTaskWithCronExpression() {
    DateTime currentT = dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
    List<Task> tasks2beDeleted = taskService.expiredTasks(DateTime currentT); 
    taskService.deleteAll(tasks2beDeleted);
}
```

Few notes:

- Your repository seems weird, it should return expired tasks not time.
- You can implement expiredTasks with db's now() method instead
- I don't know how, but if it is okey you can implement a procedure inside your db
- It seems you made a service layer that uses repository, you can also implement a service method that uses two repository method like taskService.deleteAllExpired(); which seems way better.